# mysqldump command resulting in "error 1064 syntax error"

Tags: command-line, syntax, mysql

I’m in the MySQL command line client `mysql monitor`, trying to do a `mysqldump` command on the database with which I have an open connection. This is the command I’m using at the `mysql>` prompt:

```
mysqldump -u username -p password databasename > dumpfilename.sql\g.
```

I assume that the file `dumpfilename.sql` will be created when the dump is successful. I have tried it with and without `pw`, `un`, end-of-line semicolon, etc. I am getting

> error 1064 syntax error

over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqldump` is a program, not a MySQL command. Exit the `mysql` client and enter the `mysqldump -u username -p password databasename > dumpfilename.sql` command at the shell prompt and it will work

Comment: When I quit, the client closes. Where do I find the command prompt to enter the mysqldump? And actually, fyi, I didn't download anything to get the mysqldump program... Hold on, i'll look for that now.. BRB

Comment: You don't have to download anything. How do you start the mysql command line client? What OS do you use?

Comment: It's windows 8.1, I go to the apps list and open "mysql 5.6 command line client"

Comment: It opens with the password request and then goes straight to the open connection and mysql> prompt

Comment: Open a `Command Prompt` then. I cannot tell you where to find it, I don't even know how Windows 8.1 looks like, but you can probably find it in the apps list (using Search, maybe). Then, on the command prompt you can enter the `mysqldump` command.

Comment: The command prompt is in the list of apps with everything else. The mysqldump is returning "access is denied." It's a bit of progress. I will tweek the un/pw and file path inputs for awhile and see if I can get past this. Thank you for your time and knowledge. I appreciate your instruction very much

Comment: If `mysql` command line client works you can try to find out how it is launched and replace `mysql` with `mysqldump` (and append the redirection to a file, of course). Right-click on the `mysql` item in the apps list could help; if it opens a menu then click on Properties (used to be the last entry) and you can find the command line there.

Comment: Running `mysqldump --help` on the command prompt will also help; it shows the expected parameters. `mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p database` should work. It will ask you about the password.